# XML Schema Duration Time Format - Question on Valid Values

Tags: xml, datetime, xsd

The XML format for a time interval is quoted below.  The question I have that I can't find an answer to is if there are limits to any of the values.   For example, can it be `PT5000M` for 5000 minutes or does it have to be broken down to years, months, days, hours, minutes (0-59) which can be very difficult based on starting month, if a leap year, etc..

> The duration data type is used to specify a time interval.
>
> The time interval is specified in the following form "PnYnMnDTnHnMnS"
> where:
>
> ```
> P indicates the period (required)
> nY indicates the number of years
> nM indicates the number of months
> nD indicates the number of days
> T indicates the start of a time section (required if you are going to specify hours, minutes, or seconds)
> nH indicates the number of hours
> nM indicates the number of minutes
> nS indicates the number of seconds
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You'll find the answer at

https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#duration

This gives precise rules for the lexical form, with the helpful summary

"Thus, a durationLexicalRep consists of one or more of a duYearFrag, duMonthFrag, duDayFrag, duHourFrag, duMinuteFrag, and/or duSecondFrag, in order, with letters 'P' and 'T' (and perhaps a '-') where appropriate."

So PT5000M for 5000 minutes is legal. XSD also defines rules for comparing durations, so for example PT5000M is equal to PT4999M60S. A duration value is essentially N months plus S seconds; the number of seconds in a month is variable, so PT5000M can be re-expressed in terms of days, hours, minutes, and seconds, but it doesn't equate to any duration involving years and/or months.

If you want to perform arithmetic with dates, times, and durations then I would recommend using the XPath (2.0 or later) function library.